# Show customer Data (Address, Name, etc) in Frontend/Template

Tags: customer

How can I show the customer information from a Shop-User (logged in) at my frontend template. I have some Form-PHTML-files and a customer can fill out the form etc.

I want to show "his" user data (Name, Forname, Street, City, ..) at the top of the form-template.

Who can help me?

Answer (score 7):

I found this.

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $mydatas['email'] = $customerData->getEmail();
    $mydatas['vatid'] = $customerData->getTaxvat();

    $customerAddressId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getDefaultBilling(); //oder getDefaultShipping
    if ($customerAddressId) {
        $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customerAddressId);
        $mydatas['name'] = $address->getFirstname().' '.$address->getLastname();
        $mydatas['company'] = $address->getCompany();
        $mydatas['zip'] = $address->getPostcode();
        $mydatas['city'] = $address->getCity();
        $street = $address->getStreet();
        $mydatas['street'] = $street[0];
        $mydatas['telephone'] = $address->getTelephone();
        $mydatas['fax'] = $address->getFax();
        $mydatas['country'] = $address->getCountry();
    }
}
```

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

This code depends on the fact that the user has a default billing address filled in. Only the name is standard present in an account

```
<?php

if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
{
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

    $address_id = $customer->getDefaultBilling();
    if ((int)$address_id){
       $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($address_id);

       /*
       * Insert the output here 
       * for example:
       * echo $customer->getName();
       * echo $address->getCity();
       */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For logged in customer address information, use the below code. It will work

```
<?php
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
{
    $addressIs = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getDefaultBilling();
    if ($addressIs) 
    {
        $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($addressIs);
        /* echo "<pre>";
        print_r($address);die(); */

        $mydatas['name'] = $address->getName();
        $mydatas['company'] = $address->getCompany();
        $mydatas['zip'] = $address->getPostcode();
        $mydatas['city'] = $address->getCity();
        $street = $address->getStreet();
        $mydatas['street'] = $street[0].', '.$street[1];
        $mydatas['telephone'] = $address->getTelephone();
        $mydatas['country'] = $address->getCountry();
    }
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

SPLITTING CUSTOMER ADDRESS FILED: street 0 and street 1

```
$customerAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customerAddressId);

$street = $customerAddress->getStreet();
$street0 = strtolower($street[0]);
$street1 = strtolower($street[1]);

// set "street0" as customer address...
if($street0 == $street1){
    $customerAddress->setData('street',$street0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to HTML the address:

```
public function getCustomerAddressHtml()
{
    $address = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getDefaultBillingAddress();
    return $address->format('html');
}
```

Reference the file *config.xml* in *app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc*, you can format the address in 'text', 'oneline', 'pdf', 'js_tempalte'. You can also create a customized format in your own config:

```
<global>    
    <customer>
        <address>
            <formats>
                <exthtml translate="title" module="extendedcustomer">
                    <title>EXTHTML</title>
                    <htmlEscape>true</htmlEscape>
                </exthtml>
            </formats>
        </address>
    </customer>             
</global>

<default> 
    <customer>
        <address_templates>
            <exthtml><![CDATA[{{if street1}}{{var street1}}<br />{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if city}}{{var city}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}<br/>
{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}
{{depend fax}}<br/>F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}]]></exthtml>
        </address_templates>
    </customer>
</default>
```